# How to show part of an image using QT?

Tags: c++, qt

So, this is my problem: I have this very big image, and I want to show only a specific part of it.  After the user pressing a specific key I want the image to move, showing another part of it. The transition from one part of the image to another have to be smooth, animated.

I tried using a QLabel to show the image but it always shows the center of the image, and I do not really know how to make the animation. What would you guys suggest?

Comment: Additional info: This is a big image of numbers from 0 to 9. And I want this image to scroll after the user press a key, so it would be seeing always only one number..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. Here is something I just tested and seems to work.

Add a `QGraphicsView` with dimensions the dimensions of the part of the image you want to display, eg 100x100. Create a `QGraphicsScene` and add it to the view:

```
QGraphicsScene* pScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(pScene);
```

Now add your image into the scene. In my case I has an image in my resource file. The trick is to set the `sceneRect` to the position you want to display. I wanted to display an 100x100 part of the image starting from 0,300 :

```
pItem = pScene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(":/photos/image")));
pScene->setSceneRect(0,300,100,100);
```

In order to test the smooth moving I added a button which when clicked is triggering a slot called move. This slot simply updates the `sceneRect`. In my simple example I just move the image 100 pixels right. In a real world scenario you could also move it diagonally or vertically and check the image limits.

```
void move()
{
    for (unsigned i=currentX; i<currentX + 100; i++)
    {
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->setSceneRect(i,300,100,100);
    qApp->processEvents();
    }
    currentX += 100;
}
```

Notice the `currentX` variable. It is nothing more than the last image position. Also we must call the `processEvents` in order to "see" the image moving smoothly.

Comment: Thank you. this is the closest I'vet get to what I want, but I still have some problems: the view background, can be transparent? Because it has to be.

Comment: You can use the setOpacity function on the pixmap item. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qgraphicsitem.html#setOpacity

Answer (score 2):

You could use QPixmap::copy( int x, int y, int width, int height ) to copy a region of the image and display that.

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

1. Try using a [`Q3CanvasSprite`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/q3canvassprite.html) (within in a [`Q3Canvas`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/q3canvas.html)). It is designed more for splitting one image into multiple ones but not for animating between them. You could try abusing it and declaring (say) 100 frames (10 per digit, which would be used as animation steps) or just use the `move()` method.
2. Try [`QGraphicsPixmapItem::setOffset()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qgraphicspixmapitem.html#setOffset) (within a [`QGraphicsScene`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qgraphicsscene.html#details)). This might be overkill as QGraphicsScene is made for large number of images).

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I'm working on using the GraphicsScene.
Would be great if you could put some example code, if its not asking for too much.

Comment: The Q3Canvas doesnt sounds good, since it stills in Q4 just for old code to work, and it is not guarantee that is will work in the future.

Also, the GraphicsScene looks to do more then I need?
I guess I just need to make a way of move the pixmap that I set to a Label, and use an animation for it. But Im having trouble to do so..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe this can be done with `QStateMachine` and `QAbstractAnimation`.